# Receiving Image file in java

Tags: java, sockets, file-transfer

I am  using basic java Server Client module to send a picture.

I am using this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/TransferafileviaSocket.htm) for guidance

Below is my source code for the client.I have issues while receiving the file.

```
package sclient;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Sclient {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    Socket sock = new Socket("192.168.0.10", 123);
    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024*1024];
    InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/imageTest.jpg");
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
    bos.close();
    sock.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: You doint just a single read of bytes, you need to interate over the read Method until it returns -1 as a result. Also close and flush your streams in a finally block!

Comment: How big is your file?

Comment: will try that thanks... but y they are down-voting my question? do u know?

Comment: can u give my an example of that? @Kitesurfer

Comment: So you are trying to read 1.2 MB into a 1 MB buffer ... think about it ...

Comment: Downvotes mostly are due to lack of own research and effort shown.

Answer (score 0):

Thats one util method of an android project, but its does the same. Reads and write is somewhere

```
/**
 * @param inputStream
 * @param inClose
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static byte[] readContent(@NonNull final InputStream inputStream, final boolean inClose)
        throws IOException {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(inClose, "InputStream");
    //
    final ByteArrayOutputStream theStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(BUFFER_2K);
    final byte[] theBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_2K];

    try {
        int theLength = inputStream.read(theBuffer);

        while (theLength >= 0) {
            theStream.write(theBuffer, 0, theLength);
            theLength = inputStream.read(theBuffer);
        }
        return theStream.toByteArray();
    } finally {
        if (inClose) {
            close(theStream);
        }
    }
}
```